# at command in ubuntu error 'You do not have permission to use at'

Tags: permissions, at-command

Apologize in advance, I am pretty new at php and ubuntu. I have 2 servers set up, one for development and one for staging. On the dev machine I can use the at command without a problem, but on staging I get a permissions error. The at.deny (and at.allow) files are identical, so it must be another permissions issue. Any clues? Thank you for your help. I see that on the staging server I can only use the at command as root. How can I fix this to be able to use the at command as www-data? Again... I checked the at.allow and at.deny files.. they are not the problem here. So what is?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this today.  [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/113651) implicitly suggested `chmod a+r /etc/at.allow`, which helped.  I am not sure whether this is the best/"official" way, but (a) it works for me, and (b) I don't see a lot of security risk in exposing the ids of users allowed to use `at` (at least in my use-case).