# Cannot use command at on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, 22.04

On a relatively new instance of Ubuntu 22.04, I installed at:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install at
```

Now when I try to use it as a general user, I am receiving error: "You do not have permission to use at" for a general user

I found [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803363/at-command-in-ubuntu-error-you-do-not-have-permission-to-use-at), which is an exact match for the error message, but references /etc/at.allow, which does not exist.  File /etc/at.deny does exist but does not have this user (dennis) named within it.

In debugging, I tried adding a file /etc/at.allow, with only the desired user name in its content, as follows, and the error changed:

```
> sudo su -
# echo 'dennis' > /etc/at.allow
# chmod a+r /etc/at.allow
# atd restart
# exit
> at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
Cannot open lockfile /var/spool/cron/atjobs/.SEQ: Permission denied
```

I found an answer for this permissions problem [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597681/cannot-open-lockfile-var-spool-cron-atjobs-seq) that said permissions of that .SEQ file should be 777.  I doubt that is true at all (and is instead probably a brute-force way to get around some not-understood problem), but I did try it, with the following result:

```
> sudo chmod 777 /var/spool/cron/atjobs/.SEQ
> echo 'ls' | at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 5 at Wed May 24 21:05:00 2023
Can't signal atd (permission denied)
```

What else might I try to get this to work?  Or what logs should I provide?

Comment: What does "instance" mean in this context? You'd get that error if  `/usr/bin/at` is not SETUID (and you'd tried to fix it by brute-forcing the .SEQ file).

Comment: @steeldriver - In this context, instance means 'server'.  I have a few installed, and only this one had that problem.  Problem is solved now; There were some held packages, and because of this, apt did not do the after-work ("processing triggers"), which in this case probably was to make /usr/bin/at SETUID).  After cleaning up those held packages, I did apt purge at... then apt install at.  Problem went away.  I have also set permissions back to the way Ubuntu left them.

Answer (score 2):

This was the result of aptitude not doing its post-installation work ("processing triggers") due to some held packages (notably, handbrake-related stuff).  Once I removed the 'held' (and not needed) packages, I removed at and reinstalled:

```
sudo apt purge at
sudo apt install at
```

This solved the problem.